# derech hashem and daath tevonos, same thing?

Tags: jewish-books, ramchal

I've learned Derech Hashem a few times and I'm on my second time through the English version of Da'ath Tevunos "the knowing heart" and I'm having a hard time picking out the differences between the two conceptually. Any pointers?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? Are you looking for differences such as where the Ramchal seems to hold to different positions, or differences such as facts that are included in one book and not the other? In terms of style, the two books are worlds apart, as I'm sure you've noticed

Comment: daas tevunos is much deeper

Answer (score 1):

The sefer "Derech Hashem" provides perspective about mans relationship to the world through observance of the mitzvos.

"Da'at Tevunot", written as a dialogue between the soul and the mind, involves discussions in Kabbalah, in a non-Kabbalistic language.

Part I: Deals especially with the secrets of Providence and Redemption.

Part II: Deals with the traits of man, and the purpose of man in the world.